# Using xsl, how to keep entities in hex to the output

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have a problem using xsl to process a xml and output another xml.

My input has entities in hex, like: `&#38;`
When I process this xml using saxon, I need to keep this entity like in input.

I already tried character-map or change de encode but it always transform this entity in `&amp;` or the character &.

Anybody has an idea how to solve this?

Here is an xml sample:

```
<data><name>Pilot &#38; Co-pilot Seat</name></data>
```

Here is a xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                              xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:template match="//name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As a matter of interest, WHY do you need to output the character in this form? If the XML is being read by a conformant parser, the representation of the character is immaterial. If it isn't being read by a conformant parser, then you have a major problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution,

Using xsl:character-map

But we have to add the entity &amp before the hex in string parameter like this:

```
<xsl:character-map name="isolat1">
    <xsl:output-character character="&#x0002F;" string="&amp;#x0002F;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
```

and the transformation works as expected.